# proof that $b^{\frac{m}{n}}=b^{\frac{p}{q}}$ if $\frac{m}{n}=\frac{p}{q}$

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers

So I just solved this problem, however I'm not sure if my proof works, can someone tell me if it's correct or not, also I suspect there is a much simpler way to prove it so don't hesitate to post your own proof.

The problem is: *if $m,n,p,q$ are integers, $n\gt 0,q\gt 0,$ and $r=\frac{m}{n}=\frac{p}{q},$ prove that $$(b^m)^\frac{1}{n}=(b^p)^\frac{1}{q}.$$*

First, I had to show that $b^\frac{1}{an}=(b^\frac{1}{n})^\frac{1}{a}$, which can be done by simply noting that $((b^\frac{1}{n})^\frac{1}{a})^{an}=(((b^\frac{1}{n})^\frac{1}{a})^a)^n=(b^\frac{1}{n})^n)=b,$ and since there exists a unique positive nth root for every integer we must have $b^\frac{1}{an}=(b^\frac{1}{n})^\frac{1}{a}$.

Now since $r=\frac{m}{n}=\frac{p}{q}$, without loss of generality we can write $m=ap, $ and $n=aq$ for some integer $a$ thus $(b^m)^\frac{1}{n}=(b^{ap})^\frac{1}{aq}=(((b^p)^a)^\frac{1}{a})^\frac{1}{q}=(b^p)^\frac{1}{q}.$

My main problem with this proof is that I feel like I have cheated a bit with adding the factor $a$ since it's a bit more number theoretic, and I just started doing analysis. Also I think there should be a much easier way to do it.

---

*From the comments* For a positive real $b$ and a positive integer $n$, $b^{1/n}$ is defined to be the unique positive real such that $(b^{1/n})^n = b$.

Comment: Does your factor $a$ exists for $3/3 = 2/2$? (Or if you want a less "trivial" example, $3/6 = 2/4$)

Comment: @NajibIdrissi my factor doesn't exist but I think in that case we can modify the argument to show that $3/3=1/1=2/2$ and then it works out.

Comment: Well yes, but implicitly you're using things like the GCD here, and in any case you should be explicit.

Comment: I am not quite sure how else to prove it other than going through basically the first chapter of a number theory course.

Comment: You just need the fact that every fraction has a unique representation with coprime numerator and denominator (see my answer). I think it's safe to assume that this is a known fact.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As I said in the comments, the factor $a$ doesn't necessarily exist: consider the example of $3/3 = 2/2.$

However, if you let $d = \gcd(m,n)$ such that $m = dm'$ and $n = dn'$, then $m/n = m'/n'$ and you can apply your argument to show that $(b^m)^{1/n} = (b^{m'})^{1/n'}$. Similarly, if you let $e = \gcd(p,q)$, $p = ep'$, $q = eq'$, then $(b^p)^{1/q} = (b^{p'})^{1/q'}$.

But of course $m/n = p/q \implies m'/n' = p'/q'$, and besides $\gcd(p',q') = \gcd(m',n') = 1$. But it's a standard fact every (positive) fraction has a unique representation with coprime (positive) numerator and denominator (use Euclid's lemma four times and the fact $x \mid y \text{ and } y \mid x \implies x = y$ for positive $x$, $y$), so $m' = p'$ and $n' = q'$ and the claim is proven.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Try $\dfrac{m}{n}=\dfrac{p}{q}=r$.

Then $b^{\frac{m}{n}}=b^r=b^{\frac{p}{q}}$.

Comment: Can't do that. The book hasn't yet defined rational powers other than that of the form $\frac{1}{n}$ where $n$ is some integer.

Comment: you seem happy to accept $(b^a)^{1/a}=b$, so why not $(b^p)^q=b^{p/q}$?

Comment: Actually what I accepted was that $(b^\frac{1}{a})^a=b$ this is because $b^\frac{1}{a}$ is defined to be the number such that when raised to the power of $a$ you get b. So by definition $(b^\frac{1}{a})^a=b$. You have to first prove the problem that I posted to show that it makes sense to define rational power the way you're talking about.

Answer (score -1):

For  $b>1$ use calculus. Use the exponential function, and write $b=e^a$ with $a>0$. Write $m/n=x$ and $p/q=y$.
Your question with this new notation is to show that $e^{ax}= e^{ay}$ possible only for $x=y$. Thinking of $x$ as a real variable note that $e^{ax}$ is a positive valued functions; it is monotonically increasing because its derivative is positive(being itself!).
So it is a 1-1 function.

Edit: I noticed belatedly that I have dealt with the converse assertion.